Integrating UR16e Robot in Unity3d with ROS2
I am working on a project that involves Unity3d with UR16e robot model and integrating with ROS2. I am using ROS2 Humble inside a docker container. I followed the ROS-Unity tutorials to get a hang of the integration. Now I want a similar framework but replacing niryo one robot with UR16e and ROS with ROS2. I am able to import the urdf model in unity. But I am not quite sure about the packages on the ROS2 side. I came across the packages from Universal Robotics- Universal_Robots_ROS2_Description and Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver. I have launch and config files for ur16e robot from these packages.
How do I create a package of my own which makes use of these config files and contains the scripts of simple pick and place task similar to the tutorials? My aim is to have a similar pick and place setup with UR16e robot in Unity3d supported by ROS2 for trajectory planning.
I am new to Unity and ROS2. Please help me out with this.

What have you tried and what didn't work?

Generally speaking there exists robot-state-publishers see this answer on answers.ros.org that can can read URDF/Xacro files to load a robot description and publish them as a robot description topic. That's how you handle the ROS2_Description package you linked.
